# FluentValidation "Error cs0103 the name 'x' does not exist in the current context" .asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

**Issue**

I am receiving the following error when using FluentValidation.AspNetCore (ver 8.6.1). this occurs when my edit view is saved. Very basic setup at the moment but i want to expand on the ActionValidator when it works...thanks

> Error cs0103 the name 'x' does not exist in the current context

**Code**

Startup.cs -

```
    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ActionValidator>());
```

Validation class -

```
public class ActionValidator : AbstractValidator<EditActionVM>
{
    public ActionValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ActionCompletionDate).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

**What i have tried**

Following the FluentValidation guide at  - https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#getting-started

Changing startup to use the following code -

```
    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddFluentValidation();

    services.AddTransient<IValidator<EditActionVM>, ActionValidator>();
```

**Edit**

EditActionVM.cs -

```
public class EditActionVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Action Reference")]
    public string ActionRef { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public Enums.Enums.Status Status { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Created Date")]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Action Completion Date")]
    public DateTime? ActionCompletionDate { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Ther is no variable `x` in the scope of the `ActionValidator()` function. Or the `ActionValidator` class. I am going to asume there is no static of that name either (it would also not make a lot of sense). So I am as confused as the compiler about what your goal was. Where and how is the input to be *validated* handed in?

Comment: Can you show us the EditActionVM file?

Comment: Thanks...not exactly sure what you mean there. But the setup is correct according to the following link -  https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#getting-started my ActionController checks if ModelState.IsValid which calls the validation process

Comment: @samga added thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have posted here (@Christopher that `x` is a lambda parameter, it's perfectly fine). You say the error happens when you save your *view* though, is the error in there?

Comment: @DavidG just tried with the create view also same issue...

Comment: Where is the error happening though? Show us the actual code that is giving you the problem. You haven't supplied enough detail.

Comment: @DavidG Error occurs within the ActionValidator when RuleFor(x => x.ActionCompletionDate).NotEmpty(); is called hence the "the name 'x' does not exist in the current context" error - cheers

Comment: But that code is fine, there's something else going on here then. Try restarting Visual Studio perhaps?

Comment: @DavidG i agree code is fine...have also tried a VS restart :) and rebuild...might be FluentValidation version issue? i will try and downgrade

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue with versions. I'm very confused. Which `x` in your code is highlighted as the problem?

Comment: Could it be a typing issue, perhaps a weird character has sneaked into your code. Can you delete that `RuleFor` line and type it out again manually?

Comment: Interestingly re installing the package has solved this issue...feels like it might be something in my environment that might have caused it thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling FluentValidation resolved my issue...potentially something within my environment that was causing the issue